# Working with multiple data models, helpers and reducing code repetition - C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, helper, .net-core-2.0

I'm building models and helper classes for a web service using `.Net Core 2.0`. I need to do some repetitive work on a number of models, by passing in the model and its list of objects. As of now I've defined the method entirely in each of the helper classes, as each class passes its respective model and its list of objects. The return type is also a list of objects of the same model.

Is it possible in anyway to simply this using one single method, but in every helper class I've to pass in and get back a different data model and its list along with some other parameters, which are the same for all helper classes.

I'll explain the scenario with a simple example. 
I've model classes named **FullTimeEmployee**, **PartTimeEmployee**, **ContractEmployee**, **PermanentEmployee**, **LocalEmployee** etc...

I also have Helper classes named **FullTimeEmployeesHelper**, **PartTimeEmployeesHelper**, **ContractEmployeesHelper**, **PermanentEmployeesHelper**, **LocalEmployeesHelper** etc...

In each of the helper classes I've to define a method which accepts the respective model class, list of respective employees, an int and a string. the return type is also a list of employees.

for example the method in **FullTimeEmployeesHelper** looks like

```
public static List<FullTimeEmployee> UpdateState(List<FullTimeEmployee> employeesList, FullTimeEmployee employee, int newValue, string propertyToBeUpdated) { }
```

and the method in PartTimeEmployeesHelper looks like

```
public static List<PartTimeEmployee> UpdateState(List<PartTimeEmployee> employeesList, PartTimeEmployee employee, int newValue, string propertyToBeUpdated) { }
```

I want to define one method and call it form each helper class because all the work done inside the method is the same, just the data model differs. I've tried using an Interface IEmployee but it did not work. Using an abstract class Employee also did not work. The main problem I'm facing is that all data models have different properties. There is not even a single property which is common for all the data models. The string which I pass in is the name of the property which is to be updated. The method looks for the property in the data model and changes it to the newValue which is passed as int.

Is there a way around to reduce the code repetition and use only method which can be called from all helpers?

Comment: Are you using Reflection to find the Property by using the string name? Moreover, How did you try keeping a single abstract class for all there 5 types when none of them share behavior (all have different properties)?

Comment: no. just using switch case and in some helpers where the number is very small, if .. else.. statements.

Comment: Seems like an [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination or IEmployee and  Generics. I didn't see how you wanted to use the updated property example so I have created my own implementation. In the code below I updated a property on the employee that is passed into the method. I then added this to the original list and returned it.

```
       public static List<IEmployee> UpdateState<T>(List<T> employeesList, T employee, int newValue, string propertyToBeUpdated) where T : IEmployee
    {
        T myObject = employee;

        PropertyInfo propInfo = myObject.GetType().GetProperty(propertyToBeUpdated);

        propInfo.SetValue(employee, Convert.ChangeType(newValue, propInfo.PropertyType), null);

        employeesList.Insert(employeesList.Count, myObject);

        return ((IEnumerable<IEmployee>)employeesList).ToList();

    }
```

IEmployee class:

```
    public class IEmployee
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

PartTime / FullTimeEmployee:

```
    public class PartTimeEmployee : IEmployee
{
    public int PartTimeOnly { get; set; }
}

    public class FullTimeEmployee : IEmployee
{
    public int FullTimeOnly { get; set; }
}
```

Main Program:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var newList = EmployeeHelper.UpdateState(new List<FullTimeEmployee>() { new FullTimeEmployee() { FirstName = "Ryan1", FullTimeOnly = 1 } }, new FullTimeEmployee() { FirstName = "Ryan2", FullTimeOnly = 2 }, 9, "FullTimeOnly");

        var newList2 = EmployeeHelper.UpdateState(new List<PartTimeEmployee>() { new PartTimeEmployee() { FirstName = "Roy1" } }, new PartTimeEmployee() { FirstName = "Roy", PartTimeOnly = 6 }, 2, "PartTimeOnly");
    }
```

Hopefully you can adapt this implementation to your needs. Any questions let me know.

Additional info [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)